# What is "shut" in "close the door shut"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs, parsing

I have heard the sentence "close the door **shut**" a lot. However I am not sure about the function of **"shut"**. Is it an adverb or an adjective here? How do I parse this sentence?

I am not concerned about whether the sentence is natural or idiomatic. I only want to know its grammar. Can anyone please parse it? By "parse", I mean what category of speech does each word belong to (adverb, determiner, adjective etc).

Comment: _Close the door_ and _shut the door_ mean the same. When you have closed the door, it is shut. There is no need to add another word to the instruction 'Close the door'.

Comment: In your title example "shut" is an adjective functioning as objective predicative complement of "close"

Comment: Btw, we would more naturally say "Close the door". "Shut" isn't necessary except perhaps for emphasis.

Comment: @KateBunting: There is *generally* no need to add another word, but I have heard "closed the door shut" colloquially, used to mean to close the door fully (e.g. when the door has been changed from "wide open" to "slightly ajar", and the speaker wants to specify that they wish the door to be closed completely).